# Plugging an MPPT controller into another MPPT controller

Tags: solar-charge-controller, mppt

I am installing a [CTEK D250SE](https://www.ctek.com/au/battery-chargers-12v-24v/d250se) charger into my camper trailer. The D250SE contains an MPPT controller for charging from a regular solar panel. The catch is that my existing solar panels *already* have an MPPT controller on the back of them, as the existing charging setup in this camper is very naive.

What would the impact be of plugging a solar panel that has an MPPT controller into a charger that also has an MPPT controller? I assume the controller on the solar panel will work properly, and the MPPT controller on the charger will look at the voltage/amps incoming and adjust itself accordingly. But there is scant information to confirm this.

Am I going to blow something up? Or should I be changing my solar panels to remove the MPPT controller and relying solely on the controller in the camper?

Comment: It would likely fail. for unstable  loading.  What is the real problem ?

Comment: The real problem is that I don't want to butcher these solar panels if I don't have to

Comment: I mean what specs does it not meet? Your suggestion is unscientific and wont work

Comment: You'll have to excuse me for not being a scientist, and as for "won't work" that's... what I'm asking about? I'm not making a suggestion, I'm asking if something will work. If it won't work then that's a suitable answer. I'm not sure what you're asking about which specs are not met. I tried to be very clear in what I was asking: My charger has an MPPT controller, but so do my solar panels. Will I break something if I plug my solar panels into the controller? These solar panels are used on more than one vehicle so removing the MPPT from them could be problematic.

Comment: WHat is it that the solar panel will not do? in measurable terms